# Error while executing cross-compiled program for openwrt

Tags: c, package, cross-compiling, dependency-management, openwrt

I'm trying to export a software to openwrt and i'm able to generate the ipk but the compiled file always gives me this error

> -ash: scanReportProbe: not found

I've tried everything but i'm not able to make it work. 
To be complete this is what i have done to prepare the environment:

```
git clone git://github.com/openwrt/openwrt.git
cd openwrt
./scripts/feeds update -a
./scripts/feeds install -a
make defconfig
make prereq
make menuconfig
    [here i selected the package with the M and saved the configuration]
make tools/install
make toolchain/install
make package/scanReport_probe/compile
```

I have no idea of to fix this error so i need some hint of solution.

I don't think that the error is in the code but in casse is needed this is my program:
file structure

```
scanReport_probe
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── data
    │   └── THIS IS FOR DATA FILES.txt
    ├── runScript
    │   └── scanReportProbe
    ├── scanReport_probe
    │   ├── a.c
    │   └── makefile
    └── scanReport_probe.conf
```

makefile for openwrt

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

# name of package
# version number of the sources you're using
# how many times you've released a package based on the above version number
PKG_NAME:=scanReport_probe
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_LICENSE:=MIT

# sources will be unpacked into this directory (you shouldn't need to change this)
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)

#needed 
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk


# Metadata; information about what the package is for the ipkg listings
# to keep things simple, a number of fields have been left at their defaults
# and are not shown here.
define Package/scanReport_probe
    SECTION:=utils
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    TITLE:=scanReport_probe
    URL:=https://github.com/luigiDB/scan-report_probe
    TITLE:=Scan in monitor mode probe over wifi channel with periodic report to a server through http post.
    MAINTAINER:=Please refer to github repository page
endef

define Package/scanReport_probe/description
    This is the best tool ever. 
    Scan probe over wifi and at regualar interval send results via http post.
endef


define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef


CONFIGURE_VARS+= \
    CC="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CC)"


define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/scanReport_probe $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

# We'll use the OpenWrt defaults to configure and compile the package. Otherwise we'd need to define
# Build/Configure - commands to invoke a configure (or similar) script
# Build/Compile - commands used to run make or otherwise build the source

define Package/scanReport_probe/install
    # Now that we have the source compiled (magic huh?) we need to copy files out of the source
    # directory and into our ipkg file. These are shell commands, so make sure you start the lines
    # with a TAB. $(1) here represents the root filesystem on the router.
    # INSTALL_DIR, INSTALL_BIN, INSTALL_DATA are used for creating a directory, copying an executable, 
    # or a data file. +x is set on the target file for INSTALL_BIN, independent of it's mode on the host.

    # make a directory for the config
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/scanReport_probe/

    # copy the config
    $(INSTALL_CONF) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/scanReport_probe.conf $(1)/etc/scanReport_probe

    # make a directory for some random data files required by scanReport_probe
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/share/scanReport_probe

    # copy the data files
    $(INSTALL_DATA) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/data/* $(1)/usr/share/scanReport_probe

    #make directory bin
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin

    # copy the binary
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/scanReport_probe/scanReportProbe $(1)/bin

    #make the directory init.d in case isn't present
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/init.d

    #copy script to init.d
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/runScript/scanReportProbe $(1)/etc/init.d    
endef


#runned post installation call the enable on the service
define Package/scanReport_probe/postinst
    #!/bin/sh
    # check if we are on real system
    if [ -z "$${IPKG_INSTROOT}" ]; then
        echo "Enabling rc.d symlink for scanReportProbe"
        /etc/init.d/scanReportProbe enable
    fi
    exit 0
endef


#runned pre uninstallation call the disable on the service
define Package/scanReport_probe/prerm
    #!/bin/sh
    # check if we are on real system
    if [ -z "$${IPKG_INSTROOT}" ]; then
        echo "Removing rc.d symlink for scanReportProbe"
        /etc/init.d/scanReportProbe disable
    fi
    exit 0
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,scanReport_probe))
```

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
}
```

makefile for c program

```
PROFILE = -O2 -s
CFLAGS = $(PROFILE)
LDFLAGS = 

all: main

# build it
main: a.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) a.o -o scanReportProbe

a.o: a.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.c

# clean it
clean:
    rm *.o a
```

Comment: Are you sure you have selected correct architecture in menuconfig? What does `file build_dir/target-*/scanReport_probe*/scanReportProbe` say? Compare it to a binary from your openwrt device (e.g. copy `/bin/busybox` to your host machine and run `file` on it).

Comment: Also, try removing `define Build/Compile` clause and `CONFIGURE_VARS` assignment - the defaults should work well for you.

Comment: Everything is configured correctly. I don't know why but compiling this repository git://git.openwrt.org/15.05/openwrt.git instead of the trunk solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For `-ash`, IIRC, `ash` is a [boot] shell. It is saying that it can't find a particular command.

So, it may be one of:

(1) In your rc script section, you're doing `/etc/init.d/scanReportProbe enable` but the package you're building uses `scanReport_probe`. So, you may need to add or remove an `_` here or there and/or some other renames so things match up.

(2) If the file structure you gave is the final one, I'm not sure the script is in the right directory.

(3) Are the permissions for the script correct (i.e. has execute)?

Comment: After the installation every file is in the correct directory and i' ve also tested without the init.d script just to be sure. The executable under the bin folder has execute permission `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1527 Aug 17 17:15 scanReportProbe` but also with `/bin/scanReportProbe` i receive the same error. I test also other repository that i found online and everyone gives me the same error.